# i want to reuse vagrant after i shutdown ubunto in Vertual box :

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vagrant

$ vagrant init

> > > `Vagrantfile` already exists in this directory. Remove it before
> > >           running `vagrant init`.

I want to use the existing file

Answer (score 0):

#### I want to use the existing file

Use:

```
vagrant up
```

> `Command: vagrant up [name|id]`
>
> This command creates and configures guest machines according to your
>   Vagrantfile.
>
> This is the single most important command in Vagrant, since it is how
>   any Vagrant machine is created. Anyone using Vagrant must use this
>   command on a day-to-day basis.

Source [vagrant up - Command-Line Interface - Vagrant by HashiCorp](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/up.html)

Comment: i tried  "vagrant up" but i get

λ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'base' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
==> default: Adding box 'base' (v0) for provider: virtualbox
    default: Downloading: base
    default:
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

Comment: i solve the probleme i was in the wrong directory i have to directory with the same name "emailapi" and "email_api"